# How to send email using sendrid with next js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

i have an issue with my contact form. It send email but the user input is undefined.
When i log the data on the console it is returned correctly but on vs code terminale all the information is undefined.

console log in browser dev tool return the below

```
{firstName: 'test ', email: 'test@test.com', phone: '382552', message: 'test '}
email: "test@test.com"
firstName: "test "
message: "test "
phone: "382552"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

the console log in vs code terminal

```
{
  to: 'info@test.com',
  from: 'info@test.com',
  subject: 'New message from undefined undefined',
  text: '\n' +
    '  FirstName: undefined\r\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  Email: undefined\r\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  phone:undefined\n' +
    '  Message: undefined\r\n' +
    '\n',
  html: '\n' +
    '  FirstName: undefined<br />\n' +
    '  Email: undefined<br />\n' +
    '  phone:undefined\n' +
    '  Message: undefined<br />\n',
```

The message should be containing the details log on the browser console.

api/contact

```
import cookie from "cookie";

const mail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

mail.setApiKey(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SENDGRID_API_KEY);

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default async (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader(
    "Set-Cookie",
    cookie.serialize("token", req.body.token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "development",
      expires: new Date(0),
      maxAge: 60 * 60,
      sameSite: "strict",
      path: "/",
    })
  );

  const body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

  const message = `
  FirstName: ${body.firstName}\r\n
  Email: ${body.email}\r\n
  phone:${body.phone}
  Message: ${body.message}\r\n
`;

  const data = {
    to: "info@test.com",
    from: "info@test.com",
    subject: `New message from ${body.firstName} ${body.phone}`,
    text: message,
    html: message.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br />"),
  };
  try {
    await mail.send(data);
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).json({ status: "OK" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("server error", error);
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.body);
    }
    res.status(400).json({ status: "ERROR", message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi @rob thanks for informing me about this. I have done the change, can you cancel the minus 1 please?

Comment: I did not do that.

Comment: can you log out the `message` variable? I suspect that body is not what you think it is?

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you using body-parser ([npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser))?
2. Not sure why you use `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(req.body))` seems like a waste of computer resources? This strategy is sometimes useful as the non-fastest way to deep clone an object (however [structured clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone):
   which can easily be used like `const clone = structuredClone(original);` is easier to use and probably faster).
3. what do you mean by browser's dev tool I assume that means on the client side when you make the request? So we're pretty sure the payload of the request looks good. Might be better to make sure by checking the payload in the browser's actual request (like in Chrome check Network tab of dev tools and filter to look only at Fetch/XHR then check for the specific request and it's Request Headers/Payload).
4. Next verify that the body is being received as expected and is properly being parsed by `body-parser` the defacto node-js library for parsing the body. You should be able to `console.log(req.body)` and have that show everything.
5. If that looks good and SendGrid is still not working as expected then check on the documentation.

Comment: thanks @Zargold i had to add body.data.name to get the value.